# Lotus Notes Client: How to determine user's role by click a button

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I would like to ask how to use a button to determine user's role?

I have a form and a button. I created a role called tester in Access Control List (this is used to define user's role).

What I try to do is the button will check the user's role by click it. I mean if the user is in tester role, the user clicks it, no error occurs and no action will perform at this stage. If the user is not in tester role, when the user clicks the button at the first time, there will be a pop window/message box shows to the user, if the user click more than one time, another pop window/ message box shows to the user.

I put the following code in the button to perform the action I mentioned above. I checked there is no syntax error in the code.

```
temp := @If(disablebutton="1"; @Return(@Prompt([Ok];"";"You clicked this
button more than one time.")); @Prompt([Ok];"";"This is your first time 
to click this button."));
FIELD disablebutton:="1";

@If(@IsMember("[tester]";@UserRoles);@Success;temp)
```

When I try run to test the code, I notice that if the user is not in tester role, the user will receive the message, and that works fine.

But I don't understand when the user is in tester role, the user can get the message.

Grateful if someone can let me know what I did wrong in the code.

Thank you very much.

Yours faithfully,

beginner

Comment: Hide the button when the user is in the tester role. Much move convenient - and cleans the UI (why seeing a button that doesn't do anything for "me").

Comment: Hiding things is good UI practice, but there are also times you want to execute *parts* of a formula conditionally, based on roles of field values or what have you.

Comment: Dear @muenzpraeger, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Dear Stan Rogers, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand Formula Language. Variables and fields are pretty much the same thing: they can contain values; they do not contain functions. (There are no subroutines.) When you assign something to a variable or a field, it is the value returned as a result of running a formula, not the formula itself. Most @Commands will return a 1 (@True) if they run successfully and a 0 (@False) if they don't.

If there is something that you want to skip based on user roles, you would have to do it like this:

```
@If(@IsMember("[tester]"; @UserRoles); @Return(""); "");
```

as the first line of the formula. Or, at least, as the line *before* the place in the formula where you don't want your user to go. The line says "if the user has the role '[tester]', then exit this formula without doing anything, otherwise do nothing else on this line, but continue". Use `""` as the do-nothing (no-op) in Formula Language; `@Success` should only be used for Field Validation formulas. So your formula becomes:

```
@If(@IsMember("[tester]"; @UserRoles); @Return(""); "");
@If(disablebutton="1"; @Return(@Prompt([Ok];"";"You clicked this
button more than one time.")); @Prompt([Ok];"";"This is your first time 
to click this button."));
FIELD disablebutton:="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you muenzpraeger and Stan Rogers for their comment and answer.

When I post my question, I forget to consider the User Interface issue and I found this code is useful to prevent the irrelevant role user to use the button.

```
!@IsMember("[tester]";@UserRoles)
```

I insert the code in button properties --> Paragraph Hide When tab --> checked Hide paragraph if formula is true

Then when I run to test it, it works.

Although, that code works, I will continue to study when to use the "disablebutton" in the code.

Again, I appreciate for your responses.

Thank you.

Yours sincerely,

beginner

Comment: Congratulations to you, Beginner, for discovering the value of the "See-When" formula!  That's what I call a hide-when formula that begins with "!". It's almost always easier to think of your designs in terms of when you want to see something instead of when you want to hide it! :-)